# How to send XML data in HttpBuilder request body in groovy

Tags: java, xml, grails, groovy

Here data is the XML content
How to send XML data in HttpBuilder request body in java or groovy

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)

 http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.XML) 
{
  uri.path = path
  headers.'Accept' = 'application/xml'
  headers.'Authorization' = "Basic YWU1N2UwYmFiYjUwNGJkM2I5MzI3NzQ3ODkyMjE0Yjk"
  headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'
  body:data
  response.success = { resp, reader ->
                print "================" + reader.text
            }
}
```

**Edit** This Exception is coming when i tried the 'body : XML content'

```
 Error groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Unsupported Media Type
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:652)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:953)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:508)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:390)
| Error     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)

        // perform a POST request
        http.request(Method.POST) {
            uri.path = path
            ***requestContentType = ContentType.XML***
            headers.'Authorization' = "Basic YWU1N2UwYmFiYjUwNGJkM2I5MzI3NzQ3ODkyMjE0Yjk"
            headers.'Accept' = 'application/xml'
            headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

            body = query // here Query is the XML content 
            // response handler for a success response code
            response.success = { resp, reader ->
               //Handle response here
            }

            response.failure = { resp ->

                //Handle failure here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ContentType` should be changed to `XML` and there's no `body` being sent. Try:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)

http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.XML) {
   uri.path = path
   headers.'Accept' = 'application/xml'
   headers.'Authorization' = "Basic YWU1N2UwYmFiYjUwNGJkM2I5MzI3NzQ3ODkyMjE0Yjk"
   body: //put xml body here
   //query:data not sure it this is needed, basically there are query params
   response.success = { resp, reader ->
      print "================" + reader.text
   }
}
```

Comment: But You need to change TEXT to XML as well, and please add simple xml content: `<open>1</open>`.

Comment: I have already changed this and i forgot to mention the changes. and content is also simple

Comment: I can't try it out. Is it possible to test the project online?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72560/discussion-between-yatin-makkad-and-opal).

Answer (score 0):

In [Grails](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.1/ref/Controllers/render.html) try this:

```
import grails.converters.*
…

render(contentType: "text/xml") { 
   text:yourData as XML
 }
```